# Finding the URL for podcast feeds from an iTunes id. (iTMS API)

Tags: api, rss, itunes, podcast

I'm look at a way of turning an iTunes podcast id into the RSS feed that the podcast producer serves.

I'm aware of the [RSS generator](http://ax.itunes.apple.com/rss), which can be used to generate a feed of links to podcasts, but these links are to HTML pages.

If you have iTunes open, you can manually export the list of podcasts by exporting to OPML, so we can surmise that iTunes eventually knows how to decode them (i.e. they're not exclusively going through an iTMS host).

I have looked at the [Affiliate API document](http://www.apple.com/itunesaffiliates/API/AffiliatesSearch2.1.pdf) which gives you some nice JSON back. This gives you a `collectionViewUrl` which is the same as the ones given in the RSS generator, and incidentally, the [iTunes Link Generator](http://ax.phobos.apple.com.edgesuite.net/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/wa/itmsLinkMaker). It also give you the `id`, and a whole load of other things including a preview audio file which is not hosted on the phobos.

At this point, I'm looking for anything that would help me solve this question, including any language, unofficial or not.

(in actual fact, I'd prefer something vaguely supported, and in Java, that didn't involve HTML scraping).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Through a combination of answers from [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816881/get-the-latest-podcasts-from-itunes-store-with-link-by-rss-json-or-something) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423714/get-a-list-of-itunes-podcasts-available) questions, I have found a way to do what I want.

### Example of finding podcasts

First: grab a list of podcasts from iTunes, using the RSS generator. I'm not sure how the query parameters work yet, but here is an RSS feed for top tech podcasts in the US.

```
http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/toppodcasts/sf=143441/limit=25/genre=1318/xml
```

- `sf` relates to country, and is optional. I would guess that this defaults to global if absent.
- `genre` relates to genre, and is optional. I would guess that this defaults to "all genres" is absent.
- `limit` is optional, and seems to default to 9.

This gives you an Atom feed of podcasts. You'll need to do some sperlunking with XPath to get to the ITMS id of podcast, but you're looking for the numeric id contained in the URL found at the following XPath:

```
/atom:feed/atom:entry/atom:link[@rel='alernate']/@href
```

For example, the excellent JavaPosse has an id of 81157308.

### The Answer to the Question

Once you have that id, you can get another document which will tell you the last episode, and the original feed URL. The catch here is that you need to use an iTunes user-agent to get this document.

e.g.

```
wget --user-agent iTunes/7.4.1 \
     --no-check-certificate \ 
     "https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/com.apple.jingle.app.finance.DirectAction/subscribePodcast?id=81157308&wasWarnedAboutPodcasts=true"
```

This is a plist containing some metadata about the podcast, including the feed URL.

```
<key>feedURL</key><string>http://feeds.feedburner.com/javaposse</string>
```

The XPath for this could be something like:

```
//key[@text='feedURL']/following-sibling::string/text()
```

### Disclaimer

Not entirely sure how stable any of this is, or how legal it is. YMMV.

Comment: works great for me! I am passing   --user-agent "iTunes/9.1.1"

Comment: Can confirm that this is still working as of today, so stability seems pretty good. :)

Comment: still works great today, just increase iTunes version like this : `--user-agent iTunes/12.8.0` to avoid a _showUpgradePage_ redirection.

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you have the id you can use it in lookup as defined in

https://performance-partners.apple.com/search-api

You should get what you need by parsing the response with JSON

Comment: This page no more exists.

Comment: https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

Comment: @JonathanANTOINE I have updated the link

Comment: They updated it again. https://performance-partners.apple.com/search-api

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @juhariis' answer, here's the basics of extracting the feed url  from the json (python3):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import codecs
import json

podcast_url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/grow-big-always/id1060318873'
ITUNES_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id='
parsed = urlparse(podcast_url)
id = parsed.path.split('/')[-1][2:]
reader = codecs.getreader('utf-8')
with urlopen(ITUNES_URL + id) as response:
    feed = json.load(reader(response))['results'][0]['feedUrl']
print(feed)
```

Here's a script/module I made, that makes use of this: https://gist.github.com/theychx/f9fad123bef27bebac665847c7884cd9

Comment: feedUrl is not always present so it does not work surely.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a long time to deconstruct the iTunes podcast feed. It's a plist containing meta data, of which one of them is an RSS feed. My blog post [How to subscribe to iTunes podcasts on Android](http://djchuang.com/2013/how-to-subscribe-to-itunes-podcasts-on-android/) has links to code in php and in javascript to extract the URL to the RSS feed from an individual iTunes link.