# Display List of Episodes from List of Podcasts

Tags: ios, json, ios6, rss, podcast

I am trying to display a list of podcast channels by a particular author. When a podcast is selected, display the relevant episodes. I am able to do each independently, but can't figure out how to bridge the two.

Right now my list of podcasts by author is generated using the [iTunes App Store Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html). For example, you can request

```
@"term" : @"twit", @"media" : @"podcast"
```

and it will yield all the podcast channels by the author TWiT. It includes a lot of useful metadata via JSON, such as the title, artworkUrl, etc. But no direct link to the podcast that I can find.

I can also display a list of episodes for a specific podcast by parsing the [iTunes RSS Tags](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#rss) from a hardcoded channel link that I extract by subscribing to said podcast in iTunes, then right-clicking on it and selecting Copy Podcast URL. TWiT again as an example would yield:

```
http://feeds.twit.tv/kh_video_hd.xml
```

Where this seems to fall apart is linking the two. I can't find a way to extract the direct podcast URL from the iTunes App Store JSON metadata.

I have seen the post on [Finding the URL for podcast feeds from an iTunes id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306470/finding-the-url-for-podcast-feeds-from-an-itunes-id-itms-api), but this seems to suggest you can only do it from the Apple supplied feeds from the [iTunes Store RSS Generator](http://itunes.apple.com/rss). It is limited to predefined criteria (e.g. Top Podcasts).

Suggestions or clarifications would be appreciated. The only path I'm seeing right now is to hard code each of the Podcasts channels from my author list.

Comment: What does the JSON response look like?

Comment: There is an example JSON response in the iTunes App Store Search API I linked to: http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've found the key. I'm not sure if this is universal, but in the podcasts I've tested with, the JSON results include a feedUrl parameter. Which frustratingly, is not mentioned on the [Search API page](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching).

```
feedUrl = "http://leoville.tv/podcasts/twit.xml";
```

Passing the value of this feedURL parameter pulled from the search API JSON results, and parsing it as RSS seems to deliver what I need.

Comment: Hi DenVog. I am trying to get all the feeds for a podcast , I have got a json for podcast lists by https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/genre=1304/limit=30/json   Now i need to list and play all episode for that particular selected podcast. As you mentioned above in your comment that you got  feedUrl = "http://leoville.tv/podcasts/twit.xml" for podcast. This is same what i need for each podcast. Please help me to find out this xml path.  Thanks

Comment: I have posted a question on stackoverflow too. But didn't get any useful response. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914971/apple-api-for-podcast-app-in-cocoa      Please answer me here.

Answer (score 0):

## Right Here.

```
"trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewAlbum?i=120954025&id=120954021&s=143441"
```

<sub>I think.</sub>