# Apple Api for Podcast App in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, podcast

I am creating a podcast App for mac, where user can search podcasts on itunes. Is there any Apple's built in api by which i can search and play podcast from apple itunes. Or any other api for search podcast from itunes.
Thanks

Edit:

Now i find out and list the podcast using http://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/toppodcasts/genre=1304/limit=30/json     but i am not getting  path or list of all episode for that podcast. So that i can list all episode of podcast.

After searching i find out something useful from accepted answer of this post

[Display List of Episodes from List of Podcasts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258476/display-list-of-episodes-from-list-of-podcasts?lq=1/)   But i am not getting any feed url in the json data which return me list of podcast.
Any one can tell me how i can get all episode xml/json for a podcast, like displaying in accepted answer of above post.

Comment: Did you ever finish this @Surjeet ?

Comment: @DylanBuckley: Yes, I finished this with the help of iTunes Search Api. That was the best solution which i found at that time.

Answer (score 4):

The [api documentation here](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html#searching) may be your best bet for searching. Moving that to downloading/playing the podcast is going to be a tricky proposition. Perhaps you can [use the search data to get the original rss feed](https://superuser.com/questions/78415/get-rss-feed-from-itunes-podcast-links), and then access the podcast directly from the source, rather than from iTunes.

Comment: The first link isn't opening anything